# How to check if the result of an inner join is null

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am trying to join 4 tables with inner joins, one of them with alias 'm' returns empty result set for defined condition (which is a valid possibility). I want to make a provision for the empty result set in my IF statement:

```
IF(((((SUM(m.TTL_ONLINE_COUNT)+SUM(m.TTL_OFFLINE_COUNT))*100))> TAV.`ThresholdValue`) OR ISNULL(m.TTL_ONLINE_COUNT)
```

Currently, i am trying to check if a column of that returned dataset is null but it isnt working as desired. How can i make such a provision?

```
SELECT AQ.Adate, TE.EmployeeID, TE.`WorkerLevelID`,TAV.ManufacturingProductID,TAV.SubOfficeID,Te.SubstationCode,TAV.`AllowID`,TAV.`WorkerLevelID`,TAV.ThresholdValue,TAV.RewardValue,
CASE AQ.Status
     WHEN '0' OR '6' THEN
        IF(((((SUM(m.TTL_ONLINE_COUNT)+SUM(m.TTL_OFFLINE_COUNT))*100))> TAV.`ThresholdValue`) OR ISNULL(m.TTL_ONLINE_COUNT), 
            CASE TAV.RateType 
                WHEN 'Monthly' THEN 
                    TAV.RewardValue/DAY(LAST_DAY(P_DateFrom))


                WHEN 'Yearly' THEN
                    TAV.RewardValue/365.25


            END, 0)
END   AS FPYAllowance
FROM  TempEmployee TE
INNER JOIN TempAllowValid TAV ON TE.ManufacturingProductID = TAV.ManufacturingProductID       AND TE.SubOfficeID =TAV.SubOfficeID AND TE.WorkerLevelID = TAV.WorkerLevelID
INNER JOIN Attendance_QlikView AQ ON P_DateFrom = AQ.ADate
INNER JOIN `mwooriginbasedfault` m ON m.Defect_Origin_Code = TE.SubstationCode AND m.Defect_Date = AQ.ADate
WHERE (TAV.AllowID = 3 OR Tav.AllowID=10 )
GROUP BY AQ.Adate, TE.EmployeeID);
```

Comment: If m is returning an empty result set , then the whole query will return an empty result set. Use left join if you still want to get a result.

Comment: You say it doesn't work as expected, but you do not tell what you expect.

Comment: I want that if inner join with m returns an empty result set my if statement handles it and select a '0' instead of ignoring it completely. I am sorry if i didnt make it clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to link the table `m` with a `left join` instead of an `inner join`.

The `inner join` eliminates all `TE.EmployeeID` that does not have corresponding row in table `m`. A `left join` will keep all `TE.EmployeeID` and fills the fields of table `m` with null.

Replace

```
INNER JOIN `mwooriginbasedfault` m ON 
    m.Defect_Origin_Code = TE.SubstationCode AND m.Defect_Date = AQ.ADate
```

by

```
LEFT JOIN `mwooriginbasedfault` m ON 
    m.Defect_Origin_Code = TE.SubstationCode AND m.Defect_Date = AQ.ADate
```

You should not need to provision for an empty result set in your `if` clause. The group function `sum()` accounts itself for `null` values and ignores them when calculationg the sum.